# Exporting layer to shapefile after styling using Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style

I'm trying to use Python to add a GML to my QGIS 3.4 project, apply styling to it, and then export the layer as a shapefile.

It exports the layer, but it does so before applying the styling, which uses  Rule-based symbology, which filters some data away that I want separated in different shapefiles.

I think it has to do with layer it exports, but I need it to export the layer after it added the styling to it,

```
writer5 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer5,directory + shpmap + "/road1.shp","utf-8",driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

```
import os

from qgis.core import QgsProject
directory = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
print(directory)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()


styles = "/Styles"
importfolder = "/Import"
shpfolder = "/Shpexport"
dxffolder = "/Dxfexport"

group1 ="Group"
group2 = "Analyse"
group3 = "Analyse2"

file_to_open5 = directory + importfolder +"/road1.gml"
file_to_open6 = directory + importfolder + "/road2.gml"

style5 = directory + styles +"/road1.qml"
style6 = directory + styles + "/road2.qml"


group1 = root.addGroup(group1)
group2 = root.addGroup(group2)
group3 = root.addGroup(group3)

layer5 = QgsVectorLayer(file_to_open5, "road1", "ogr")
if not layer5.isValid():
    print ("road1 failed to load!")
else:
    print ("road1 was loaded successfully!")
    layer5.loadNamedStyle(style5)
group1.addLayer(layer5)

layer6 = QgsVectorLayer(file_to_open5, "road2", "ogr")
if not layer6.isValid():
    print ("road2 failed to load!")
else:
    print ("road2 was loaded successfully!")
    layer6.loadNamedStyle(style6)
group1.addLayer(layer6)


writer5 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer5,directory + shpmap + "/road1.shp","utf-8",driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
writer6 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer6,directory + shpmap + "/road2.shp","utf-8",driverName="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: I figured it out, my assumption that the styling didnt export was wrong. The styling doesnt filter the output for the objects. You need to add a 
layer.setSubsetString("put your filter here") for queries you want filtered from your data. After adding this, it exported the layer correctly with the filters in place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, my assumption that the styling didnt export was wrong. The styling doesnt filter the output for the objects. You need to add a

```
layer.setSubsetString("put your filter here")
```

for queries you want filtered from your data. After adding this, it exported the layer correctly with the filters in place!